# Salesforce - SOQL - Unknown error parsing query

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have 2 SOQL Queries when ran independently work great

**Query 1**

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  Name, 
  District_Name__c 
FROM 
  Public_School_District__c 
where 
  District_Name__c = 'AL'
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT 
  District_Name_Formula__c 
FROM 
  Community_Interest__c 
where 
  District_Name_Formula__c = 'AL'
```

When I tried joining the query

```
    SELECT 
  Public_School_District__c.Id, 
  Public_School_District__c.Name, 
  Public_School_District__c.District_Name__c, 
  Community_Interest__c.District_Name_Formula__c 
FROM 
  Public_School_District__c 
  INNER JOIN Community_Interest__c ON Public_School_District__c.District_Name__c = Community_Interest__c.District_Name_Formula__c 
WHERE 
  Public_School_District__c.District_Name__c = 'AL' 
  AND Community_Interest__c.District_Name_Formula__c = 'AL'
```

Like this it throws `Unknown error parsing query` what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for the `INNER JOIN` clause in SOQL. Instead, you should use the `IN` operator to filter the records. So something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, District_Name__c 
FROM Public_School_District__c 
WHERE District_Name__c = 'AL' 
  AND Id IN (SELECT Public_School_District__c 
             FROM Community_Interest__c 
             WHERE District_Name_Formula__c = 'AL')
```

You can find additional information regarding SOQL comparison operators [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm).